# How to Inner Join two Tables based on 2 JSON object columns?

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join, select

I have two tables: all_UnitData and all_TrooperData which has 2 columns each. One is a Varchar column and the other is a JSON object. I have attached the two tables. PS: I have limited the rows to 5.
I want to combine these two tables(inner join) and the only common value is one of the values in the JSON object (STUID). How can I inner join these two tables using a JSON object value?

[image]

Here is my query:

```
 Select JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.A') as 'STID', JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.B') as 'Rank', 
 JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.J') as 'Role', JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.G') as 'Category',
 JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.E') as 'Height', JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.F') as 'Weight', 
 JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.C') as 'Gender', JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.H') as 'Status', 
 JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.I') as 'STUID',
 JSON_Extract(STUnitInfo,'$.A') as 'BGID', JSON_Extract(STUnitInfo,'$.B') as 'Designation', 
 JSON_Extract(STUnitInfo,'$.E') as 'STUID2'
 **FROM all_TrooperData INNER JOIN all_UnitData ON concat(all_UnitData,'.',JSSTUID = all_TrooperData.STID**
```

(this is where i have an issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you want:

```
SELECT 
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.A' as STID, 
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.B' as Rank, 
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.J' as Role, 
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.G' as Category,
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.E' as Height,
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.F' as Weight,
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.C' as Gender,
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.H' as Status,
    td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.I' as STUID,
    ud.STUnitInfo  ->> '$.A' as BGID,
    ud.STUnitInfo  ->> '$.B' as Designation,
    ud.STUnitInfo  ->> '$.E' as STUID2
FROM all_TrooperData td
INNER JOIN all_UnitData ud 
    ON ud.STUnitInfo ->> '$.E' = td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.I'
```

Notes:

- the `->>` operator shortens the query - and it properly unquotes JSON values, which you probably want
- table aliases make the query easier to read and write
- do not surround column aliases with single quotes - they are meant for literal stings

Comment: THANK YOU..that worked ! May i ask if we can do the same drill using JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.C') syntax instead of td.TrooperInfo ->> '$.C'  syntax. Just want to make sure if my syntax was wrong or if the same problem can be solved by JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.C') syntax . I tried using this syntax, but i got an error. Could you help show me how to solve this problem using the JSON_Extract syntax as well.

Comment: @Roger: it should work fine with `JSON_EXTRACT()` too. Note that It would be cleaner to surround `JSON_EXTRACT()` this with `JSON_UNQUOTE()` so values are properly unquoted.

Comment: @GMB- How would the syntax look like with JSON Extract? is it: td.JSON_Extract(TrooperInfo,'$.A') as STID  ?

Comment: @Roger: no, `JSON_EXTRACT(td.TrooperInfo, '$.A')` (the table alias prefixes the column name). Or better yet: `JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(td.TrooperInfo, '$.A'))`.